# ARCore Not supported CAT products

Tags: arcore

We are a product development company that face the problem of product irreplaceability. Google play services for AR (ARCore) in the google play store are Not supported for CAT products (s62 pro model). Can this be solved? What is the issue with this? Can support service help?

Answer (score 0):

You really got to be on their upgrade-treadmill to have an ARCore App, more so than other API's because they probably are really targeting some future hardware, like smart glasses. I know its very frustrating when they break BOTH forward and reverse compatibility! I just hope its not a side-effect of their employees working from home...

Comment: How can I get closer to personal/service employees?

Comment: I've been and Android developer from the start and my experience is that Google employees are highly insulated, in part because they are bombarded my thousands of requests a day and cannot help any one person or company. The only connection I have had with a Google employee is that I went to funeral of his Grandmother, who was a friend of my Mom...